# Android mixing raw sounds. Source is java arrays not files or recourses

Tags: android, audio, soundpool, audiotrack

I have audio data in uncompressed raw format as java arrays.
short[] or byte[] 
I wish to play them in Android.

SoundPool looks like what I need but I can't find way to load data from memory. It loads from files only and I am not sure how do I specify format that it is raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) class has `write(...)` methods which accept `byte[]` or `short[]` as the source parameters. It's the only Android sound class I know of that does.

Comment: I seen examples with `AudioTrack` It is often used in multithreaded manner. Is it possible to use it in single thread to mix 10 channel with FX effects like explosions and other short sounds? Does it mix in software or hardware?

Answer (score 1):

A library called [libpd](https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android) can give you many audio features lacking in Android. The learning curve is a bit steep, but it's powerful stuff.